# Best performance for SQL DB design?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, performance, database-design

I have a question about DB design and performance.

Imagine the following scenario:

I have a `Product` table, each record of products might have different color, different weight and different type. when I want to design my database I have have 2 ways:

1. I can design 3 tables, a `Productcolor` table with `ProductID` and `Color` columns, then one for `ProductSize` with `ProductID`, weight columns, and a `ProductType` table with `ProductID` and `Type`. And repeat one product with different colors, wights and types. and use join to have total properties.
2. I can have color, weight, type columns in `Product` table and separate different values by a separator like ",".

I have some tables like this one, now i want to know is there any better solution for such a scenario? if not which one has better performance in sql and even in my asp.net project?

Comment: #1 would be almost the proper database normalization you should strive for - approach #2 is an ugly hack that'll cause you grief and worry and lost productivity over and over and over again in the lifespan of your application ....

Comment: As many have said, .dot separated field, classic bad idea unless you don't and never ever ever will wish to find products with one or more of those properties in sql query. If that were true, then you'd be better off choosing a NoSQl variant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have given, I would have a single table with columns for product id and name, and 3 separate columns for colour, weight, and type. Depending on other requirements, I might separate out colour and type out to separate tables.

In your second suggestion, are you talking of putting colour weight and type in one column, presumably a string containing something like "Red, 2kg, Widgets"? If so, never do this. It's the worst possible way to put stuff into a database.

Comment: no, in second way i meant 3 separate columns, with separated values of each attribute. eg: color column = red, blue, black. Weight column = 120k, 130k ...

Answer (score 0):

try this example!

Create a products table as

```
Product_Id | Product_Name 
1          | Product's first name
```

Now, use another table and write the properties and settings to it! This way,

```
Product_Id | Product_Color | Product_Weight | Product_Type
1          | Color of it   | Its weight     | Type of it!
```

Now, if you want to store them (color, weight, type) too, you can create seperate tables for them too! Like this:

```
Color_Id | Color_Name
1        | Red
2        | Green
```

Now, after all this you can just save the `Color_Id` in the `Product_Properties`.

Database design has some properties and some rules, which must be followed for a better Database design! Which includes, that

1. Each type of data must have its own table!
2. Data must not replicate (duplicate data must be removed or moved to a place with a seperate data identity)
3. You must try to store Primary Key for the data and use it!

Keep these in mind and you will be able to create Database's better design! Which would be easy for you too.

Comment: these attributes are not related to each other, so i will have 3 sub table that each of them has just 2 columns, for instance Productid and colorid. or productid and type... is it well? in this way i will have too many tables!

Comment: You can create as many tables as you want @maryammohammadi .. but the only common thing among them will be the `Product_Id`..by which you will distinct the products so that each has its own propert! :)